# QtableWidget: How to find value in specific column

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I need to check wether a specific value is in a specific column using qtablewidget.
In my case I need to check the first column wether an ID is allready existing, if yes I need the number of the containing row to update this row otherwise I like to add the row. 
Is there any solution provided by QT to check the column or shou

Comment: Can you please tell us more about the underlying model for the `QTableWidget`. I.e. Are you using a custom model class? That can help steer answers to your particular use case.

Comment: I just use the standard widget. I'm just beginner in QT an c++ so maybe I don't understand the Queston right.

Comment: @Matthew `QTableWidget` has its own model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that you are looking for your value in first column (that why second argument in item(int,int) is 0) and table name is myQTableWidget

```
int rows = myQTableWidget->rowCount();
bool found = false;
for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    if(myQTableWidget->item(i, 0)->text() == "Something")
    {
        //we have found our value so we can update 'i' row
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!found)
{
    //we didn't find our value, so we can insert row
}
```

Comment: This of course will work... but not an optimize version of search. Any better idea ?

Comment: @swdev To optimize this, start by using `QTableView` and your own `QTableModel`.

Comment: You may also use QTableWidget::findItems: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidget.html#findItems