# Replacing a row in QTableWidget based on cell name

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

Lets say I have QTableWidget that looks like this:

```
__| columnname1 | columnname2
1 | name1       | value1
2 | name2       | value2
3 | name3       | value3
4 | name4       | value4
```

that I created with this code:

```
ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(2);
foreach(const QString& key, keys)
        {
            value = jsonObj.value(key);
            ui->tableWidget->sortItems(int (1),Qt::DescendingOrder);
            int currRow = ui->tableWidget->rowCount();
            ui->tableWidget->setSortingEnabled(false);
            ui->tableWidget->insertRow(ui->tableWidget->rowCount());
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(currRow, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(key));
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(currRow, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(value.toString()));
            ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels({"columnname1", "columnname2"});
            ui->tableWidget->setSortingEnabled(true);
            ui->tableWidget->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
    }
```

Now, for example, I have a new value for name2, how can I replace that entire row where name2 is?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392395/qtablewidget-how-to-find-value-in-specific-column

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're calling some functions for every row that only need to be called once for the full table. Instead, your code sample should look more like this:

```
ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(2);
ui->tableWidget->setSortingEnabled(false);
ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels({"columnname1", "columnname2"});
ui->tableWidget->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
foreach(const QString& key, keys)
{
    value = jsonObj.value(key);
    int currRow = ui->tableWidget->rowCount();
    ui->tableWidget->insertRow(ui->tableWidget->rowCount());
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(currRow, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(key));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(currRow, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(value.toString()));
}

ui->tableWidget->sortItems(int (1),Qt::DescendingOrder);
ui->tableWidget->setSortingEnabled(true);
```

Then, if you have a new *value* for the row 'name2', you only need to replace the value. You already know how to do that:

```
// first find the row index of row 'name2':
int rowIdx = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < ui->tableWidget->rowCount(); i++) {
    if(ui->tableWidget->item(i, 0)->text() == "name2") {
        rowIdx = i;
        break;
    }
}
if(rowIdx >= 0) {
    // then EITHER replace the item:
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(rowIdx, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(value.toString()));
    // OR replace the data:
    ui->tableWidget->item(rowIdx, 1)->setText(value.toString());
}
```

I didn't compile this sample code, it could have typos or wrong function names, but you'll get the idea.

Comment: I'm not sure why but entire row I want to change is deleted when I use this code

Comment: Do you mean deleted or cleared (empty fields)? Which method did you use? `new QTableWidgetItem` or `setText`?

Comment: Its cleared, sorry, my bad. I used the same code you provided with some adjustments for my needs.. so:
```
        int rowIdx = -1;
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < ui->tableWidget->rowCount(); i++) {
            if(ui->tableWidget->item(i, 0)->text() == keys.first()) {
                rowIdx = i;
                break;
            }
}

        if(rowIdx >= 0) {
            ui->tableWidget->setItem(rowIdx, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(value.toString())); //replace the item
            ui->tableWidget->item(i, 0)->setText(value.toString()); //replace the data
}
```

Comment: There was a bug in my sample. But you also discarded my comments: **Either** replace the item **or** replace the data. Doing both is not necessary. Also you strongly need to debug your code and see if `value` actually has content.